# How to re-route every pages that doesn't exist or is unauthorized to visit in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Basically, I am trying to re-route every pages that doesn't exist to a 404 page under my public folder.

So far what I did on my applications_controller.rb I place the ff:

```
rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :show_404
```

But still when I tried to visit a page that doesn't exist like: `http://localhost:3000/dashboard/pagedo`

It's just showing this instead of the 404 page:

[image]

What do I need to do, to do this? Do I need to setup some codes on `routes.rb`?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a match-all route ([`via: :all` means "match all HTTP verbs"](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#http-verb-constraints)), which needs to be placed at the **bottom** of your `config/routes.rb` file:

```
match '*path', via: :all, to: 'errors#page_not_found'
```

And then handle it in a controller, in the same manner as your exception handling above:

```
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
  def page_not_found
    show_404
  end
end
```

Comment: A small word of warning: In some cases, this might cause lots of test failures - i.e. if you were explicitly testing that certain routes should *not resolve*. But for example, you could just update these tests to either expect routes to resolve to this `page_not_found` action, or alternatively test that the actual requests get a 404 response.

Comment: could you please explain why `'*'` doesn't work but `'*path'` (as you said) works? I'd expect `'*'` to match any path and `'*path'` any path ending with `path` string.

Comment: @Saulo *"I'd expect `'*'` to match any path and `'*path'` any path ending with path string"* -- That's not [how it's documented as working](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments). Rails sets the path wildcard name as a parameter (as per the linked docs), so I guess that's why it doesn't support an un-named wildcard segment.

Comment: @Saulo To define a wildcard segment that ends in a specific pattern, you could do this with [a constraint](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-constraints).

Comment: Thank you so much! I wasn't aware of these named segments feature!

Answer (score 1):

Tom Lord's answer is good if you want to map all of the non-matching routes in Development to a 404 page; however, in Rails all non-matching routes are mapped to the 404 in `public/404.html`.You can actually test this out by running

`RAILS_ENV=production bin/rails s`

from the root of your project and visiting a page that doesn't exist. With this you maintain the useful route matching 404 help page in development.